# TypeError: ("sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'", 'occurred at index city_code')

Tags: pandas

`df_mxm_cstmrs_grp[['city_code']].count()`

```
       city_code
city_code   
1.0    22408
2.0    22630
3.0    23770
4.0    24290
5.0    23767
6.0    21163
7.0    23276
8.0    22854
9.0    21821
10.0   22965
```

When i try to sort the city_code with below code I got the error

`df_mxm_cstmrs_grp[['city_code']].count().apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['city_code']))`

Comment: Why did you use `apply`?

Comment: @E.Zeytinci  `df_mxm_cstmrs_grp[['city_code']].count().sort_values(['city_code'],ascending=False)`  I got value error `ValueError: 'city_code' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.`

Comment: Doesn't that give you the result you want?`df_mxm_cstmrs_grp.groupby('city_code').size().rename('count').reset_index().sort_values(by='count', ascending=False)`

Comment: @E.Zeytinci  i got error `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
`

Comment: Can you try before you group? I think it will give you the result you want.

Comment: @E.Zeytinci, its working, is it because of i need to do reset_index `city_code ` for the df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this before `groupby`. It will give you the result you want,

```py
(df_mxm_cstmrs_grp.groupby('city_code')
    .size()
    .rename('count')
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by='count', ascending=False))
```